# How do I clear data shown on mouseenter with onmouseout

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, web

When the user hovers over an image an information box comes up about that image, the information them changes inside the box as I move over another image but when I am over no images the information box stays. I can't close the information box (i.e. tooltips).

**JS :**

```
var id;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').mouseenter(function () {
        //var id = $(this).parent().attr('myval');
        id = $(this).data('myval');
        $.ajax({//create an ajax request to foliobase.php
            type: "GET",
            //link to the foliobase.php file "?subj" here is the connector
            url: "foliobase.php?subj=" + id,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (response) {
                $("#fillFolio").html(response);
            }
        });
    });
    $('a').onmouseleave(function () {
        id  = $(this).data.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

How can I get the information box to disappear on mouse out?
I have tried multiple tests but the box doesn't even appear with them, the last one I tried is in the code above.

```
    $('a').onmouseleave(function () {
        id  = $(this).data.display = 'none';
    }
```

I am only starting out with javascript, jquery etc. in the last year.

Thank you in advance!!

Here is the php.

```
<div class="thumbnails">
<?php
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "select * from portfolio");
    print "<ul>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {print "<li><a href=\"javascript:return(0)\" data-myval=".$row['folio_id'] . "><img onClick=preview.src=" . $row['image'] . "name=" . $row['folio_id'] . "src={$row['image']}></a></td></li>";
    }
    print "</ul>";
    ?>
</div>

<!--Folio Information-->
<div id="fillFolio">Project Information</div>
```

Comment: Add your HTML code please.

Comment: `$("#fillFolio").empty();` ???

Comment: `$("#fillFolio").removeAttr('value');` It will remove `value` from the element

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but try to use :

```
$('a').onmouseleave(function () {
    $("#fillFolio").empty();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").hover(function(){
       id = $(this).data('myval');
        $.ajax({//create an ajax request to foliobase.php
            type: "GET",
            //link to the foliobase.php file "?subj" here is the connector
            url: "foliobase.php?subj=" + id,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (response) {
                $("#fillFolio").html(response);
            }
        });
    }, function(){
//im not sure u want to hide or want to just clear your question not clear
    $("#fillFolio").empty();
    $("#fillFolio").hide();
});
```

Comment: if you use `hide()` the box will not show on hover.

Comment: but he can show after he getting response;
 $("#fillFolio").html(response);
 $("#fillFolio").show();

Comment: Because he not use show that mean the box is already shown. and cause no prob when it's empty for the first time.

Comment: Thanks for all your input!                                                                              I want it to work like a tool tip, It's for a portfolio site so when I hover over one of my designs a box appears with info on the project and the box disappears when leaving the image, none of the above examples worked, could it be that there is a jquery collision going on?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use jQuery hover = (mouseenter + mouseleave)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var id;
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').hover(function () {
        //var id = $(this).parent().attr('myval');
        id = $(this).data('myval');
        $.ajax({//create an ajax request to foliobase.php
            type: "GET",
            //link to the foliobase.php file "?subj" here is the connector
            url: "foliobase.php?subj=" + id,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (response) {
                $("#fillFolio").html(response);
            }
        });
       ,function () {
          id  = $(this).empty();
    });
</script>
```